# Display multiple values on one line in mysqli generated dropdown box

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Using mysqli code, I have been able to create a  dropdown box using data from a mysql database. The sql statement selects the userId, f_Name, and l_Name from the database. This list is part of a form and when the user selects the name, I want to pass only the userId via the $_Post method. How can that be done? Thanks again for your help.

```
<select name="names">
    <option value = "">---Select---</option>
    <?php
        $queryusers = 'SELECT userID, f_Name, l_Name FROM users';
        $db = mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryusers);
        while ( $names=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
           echo "<option value='{".$names['f_Name']."}' . 
                {".$names['l_Name']."}'>".$names['f_Name']. " " .
                $names['l_Name']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Make the `value` the `id`, not the `name`. Also you should take out the curly braces (unless there is a reason for those?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$names['userID'].'" >'.$names['f_Name'].' '. $names['last_nm'] . '</option>';
```

that becomes the value of the option, which is what gets submitted.

**Edit**

This is your code using this

```
<select name="names">
    <option value = "">---Select---</option>
    <?php
        $queryusers = 'SELECT userID, f_Name, l_Name FROM users';
        $db = mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryusers);
        while ( $names=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
           echo '<option value="'.$names['userID'].
            '" >'.$names['f_Name'].' '. $names['last_nm'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

**another edit to show the mysqli prepared statement example**

Assuming you are inserting these same values into a table, you'd just do it like this:

Your mysqli connection would be something like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname)
```

Then you'd do your insert like this (assuming userID is an autoincrement key)

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("insert into users (userID, f_name, L_name)
                       values (NULL, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $names['f_name'],$names['l_name'])
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The `"ss"` just means both variables are strings;  if they are integers you'd use `i`.   If you are doing an update, you'd just replace any variables you'd use in the insert with those `?` placeholders.  It works the same way.

Here's the manual: [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: It is not critical but if possible it would enhance security to not show the userId in the dropdown but still display the first & last names. Is that possible?

Comment: It really wouldn't enhance security that much.  It's just better from the point of view of using something like a primary key on your database.   If you want to make the security better, you should use prepared statements when submitting

Comment: I find it is a lot easier to manage data working off of keys (like ids) then first name/last name combinations.  Those are just good for readability

Comment: I agree with your comment about managing data off of keys (& the userID is a primary key) in my database. I tried for about 2 1/2 days to get the dropdown list to work under that premises but could not so I gave up and went this route. I would really be interested to see what your solution looks like using the primary key to create the dropdown and pass the primary key value to the &_POST. I know this is would be extra work and if you don't want to I will totally understand. Thanks again.

Comment: Isn't that what was just done?   the userID (I'm assuming this is a primary key, but I don't know how your tables are structured) is what should work.  This is what will be submitted.  The composite first name/last name combo is only what will display but it is tied to the userID.   try it out

Comment: If there's some other problem (e.g. your insert or update), include that code.

Comment: The solution you provided works great. I am sorry about the confusion. I was referencing how to use prepared statements do accomplish the same outcome.

Comment: oh sure.  I'll provide an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83008/discussion-between-wally-fisher-and-nomistic).